# Changing an exponential function to logarithmic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I have a question stating that $P=75e^{-0.005t}$ and they want to get t by itself.

I used the example $y=2^x = x=log_2(y)$

To find that $-0.005t = 75ln(P)$

So $t=\frac{75ln(P)}{-0.005}$

However apparently this isn't correct. Can someone please show me where I went wrong (not so much another way of doing it, but what was wrong in the working I used)

Thanks

Comment: You need $\ln \frac{P}{75}$, not $75\ln P$.

Comment: Is there a rule that you could state for that as the example I used    doesn't say anything about what the 75 should be doing

Comment: Log(P) = Log(75) + Log(Exp(-0.005 t)) = Log(75) - 0.005 t. Then, t= ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align} P=75e^{-0.005t} & \iff \dfrac P{75} = e^{-0.005t} \\ \\ &\iff \ln\left(\frac P{75} \right) = \ln\left(e^{-0.005t}\right) \\ \\ & \iff \ln\left(\frac P{75} \right) = -0.005t \\ \\ & \iff t = -\left(\frac{\ln P - \ln (75)}{0.005}\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: In that last step. How come it becomes $\frac{lnP-ln(75)}{0.005}$ rather than $\frac{ln(\frac{P}{75})}{0.005}$

Comment: One of the logarithm rules is that $$\ln \left(\frac ab\right) = \ln a - \ln b$$ (Just as $\ln(ab) = \ln a + \ln b)$

Comment: Ah I get it. Cheers

Comment: @amWhy: Nice feedback +1

Answer (score 1):

P=75exp(-0.005t) ===> ln(P) = ln(75) + ln(exp(-0.005t)) ===> ln(P) = ln(75) - 0.005t  ===> t= (ln(P) - ln(75))/-0.005

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  This solution is not very easy to read; please consider breaking it up some.  (Don't be afraid to use words to describe what you're doing -- it makes your communication much clearer!)  You can also learn about typing mathematics on this site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).